# Easiet software to create a GUI for beginner programmers?

Tags: user-interface

I am in my first year of programming and I was assigned to create a GUI using software such as Dreamweaver, VB, ect. I was hoping to get some input on how to go about this project, without learning a boat load of code or a software I am unfamiliar with. 
I am familiar with DW and VB, but not really sure how to create a GUI using VB. I have heard of a designer feature in VB.

Comment: Windows? Web? Mobile? Touch? Console? Cross-platform? Business? App? Animation? Game? The task and target/requirements are important when making initial decisions such as this - this question is far too broad.

Comment: @user2864740 Console or Windows. And it does not have to be functional. I just have to demonstrate the layout (such as buttons and menu options) for the user

Comment: There are many ["UI mockup"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ui+mockup) tools available, perhaps one of them would be more appropriate for this task?

Comment: @user2864740 When you say UI mockup tools, do you mean those are available in DW or VB? or do you mean other programs feature that?

Comment: I mean tools not associated with either DW or VB that can be used to quickly create [*mockups*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockup) - of course choose the tool that actual mocks the intended target! The search link provided in the previous comment yields a number of good examples. Then, when you're ready to write *functional* code, choose the appropriate language/environment/library (see my first comment) and go.

Comment: @user2864740 Maybe when they're ready to write *imperative* code, they should choose the appropriate language/enviroment/library. There is no such thing as *functional* GUI code, pun intended.

Comment: @John I use the *RL* monad. Captures state exactly. Haven't quite figured out how to keep around previous values .. (which would be very handy for "feature" reports)

Comment: @user2864740 I'm unfamiliar with that monad. I like my functional languages pure. Me avoid monad like nomad avoid me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using anything after Visual Basic 6 & are programming for Windows, Visual Studio comes with one. Should be File->New->New Project->Visual Basic->Windows->Windows Form Application or similar depending on the edition & settings of Visual Studio (The 'form' is the relevant part)

If you are a student, you can get Visual Studio Professional at DreamSpark. If not, you can get Visual Studio Express Visual Basic for free.